# Application is not starting up in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have added my `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` dependency to my existing project. After that I added the related REST Controller and created the methods to get the data from MongoDB.

For a first few times, it did not have any problem during start up and it was successfully connecting to the db which I can see in the log. After I completed my code, I tried to bring it up again but I started getting error. The staack trace is like the following:

```
2019-06-18 09:46:40,172 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate [RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java : 163] Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2019-06-18 09:46:40,240 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate [RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java : 163] Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2019-06-18 09:46:40,428 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate [RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java : 163] Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2019-06-18 09:46:40,443 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.intake.repository.IntakeRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,444 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.ContactProtocolRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,444 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.ExternalSourceRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,445 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.LocAttributeRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,446 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.NHCoordCareSettingRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,446 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrganizationCountRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,447 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrganizationRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,448 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgContactMethodRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,448 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgEnvironmentTypeRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,448 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgExternalSourceRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,449 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgRelationshipRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,449 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgRelationshipServiceRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,450 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgRelationshipTagRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,450 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgServiceAreaRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,450 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgServiceRatingRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,450 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.OrgServiceRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,451 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.RatingSourceRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,451 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.RelationshipTagsRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:40,451 INFO [main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport [RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java : 283] Spring Data MongoDB - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.orgname.csi.datasync.organization.repository.RelationshipTagTypeRepository.
2019-06-18 09:46:41,035 INFO [main] o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol [DirectJDKLog.java : 180] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
2019-06-18 09:46:41,042 INFO [main] o.a.c.c.StandardService [DirectJDKLog.java : 180] Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-06-18 09:46:41,042 INFO [main] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine [DirectJDKLog.java : 180] Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2019-06-18 09:46:41,045 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.AprLifecycleListener [DirectJDKLog.java : 180] The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;.]
2019-06-18 09:46:41,201 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/] [DirectJDKLog.java : 180] Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-06-18 09:46:41,494 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] c.c.c.d.c.MongoConfiguration [MongoConfiguration.java : 37] host is db-mongodev.orgname.local
2019-06-18 09:46:41,494 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] c.c.c.d.c.MongoConfiguration [MongoConfiguration.java : 38] port is 27017
2019-06-18 09:46:41,494 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] c.c.c.d.c.MongoConfiguration [MongoConfiguration.java : 39] database is orgdatabase
2019-06-18 09:46:42,403 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] o.m.d.cluster [SLF4JLogger.java : 71] Cluster created with settings {hosts=[db-mongodev.orgname.local:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2019-06-18 09:46:42,674 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] i.s.c.AbstractJestClient [AbstractJestClient.java : 57] Setting server pool to a list of 1 servers: [https://mavdv-cisels-01.orgname.local]
2019-06-18 09:46:42,676 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] i.s.c.JestClientFactory [JestClientFactory.java : 222] Using multi thread/connection supporting pooling connection manager
2019-06-18 09:46:42,737 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] i.s.c.JestClientFactory [JestClientFactory.java : 70] Using custom GSON instance
2019-06-18 09:46:42,737 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] i.s.c.JestClientFactory [JestClientFactory.java : 85] Node Discovery disabled...
2019-06-18 09:46:42,737 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] i.s.c.JestClientFactory [JestClientFactory.java : 97] Idle connection reaping disabled...
2019-06-18 09:46:42,738 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] i.s.c.JestClientFactory [JestClientFactory.java : 102] Authentication cache set for preemptive authentication
2019-06-18 09:46:43,104 INFO [cluster-ClusterId{value='5d08f952f7b760161855baf9', description='null'}-db-mongodev.orgname.local:27017] o.m.d.connection [SLF4JLogger.java : 71] Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1}] to db-mongodev.orgname.local:27017
2019-06-18 09:46:43,193 INFO [cluster-ClusterId{value='5d08f952f7b760161855baf9', description='null'}-db-mongodev.orgname.local:27017] o.m.d.cluster [SLF4JLogger.java : 71] Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=db-mongodev.orgname.local:27017, type=SHARD_ROUTER, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 2, 17]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=4, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=null, roundTripTimeNanos=87442300}
2019-06-18 09:46:54,402 INFO [main] c.c.c.d.c.GeoCodeApiConfiguration [GeoCodeApiConfiguration.java : 28] Geo api using auth id: 2af30031-f6aa-bf3f-9906-492c7364700b
2019-06-18 09:46:54,560 INFO [main] o.a.c.c.StandardService [DirectJDKLog.java : 180] Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-06-18 09:46:54,564 WARN [localhost-startStop-2] o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase [DirectJDKLog.java : 180] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-ClusterId{value='5d08f952f7b760161855baf9', description='null'}-db-mongodev.orgname.local:27017] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForSignalOrTimeout(DefaultServerMonitor.java:226)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.waitForNext(DefaultServerMonitor.java:207)
 com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:154)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-06-18 09:46:54,564 WARN [localhost-startStop-2] o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase [DirectJDKLog.java : 180] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [CleanCursors-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If you see the log the cluster id it mentions in the end is the same cluster id that got created in the same session and as Tomcat stopped it could not terminate the process. So it might be that for a different reason Tomcat is stopping which I am not able to debug. Can anyone help?

my MongoSearch class is  the following:

`    package com.orgname.csi.datasync.repository;

```
 import com.orgname.csi.datasync.configuration.MongoConfiguration;
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
 import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Map;

 public class MongoSearchRepository<T> {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoSearchRepository.class);

@Autowired
MongoConfiguration mongoConfig;
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = mongoConfig.mongoTemplate();

//To search for a document with a where clause
protected List<T> findIs(Map<String,String> queryParams, Class<T> clazz){
    Query query = new Query();
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : queryParams.entrySet()){
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(entry.getKey()).is(entry.getValue()));
    }
    logger.debug("Query created is {}",query);
    logger.debug("The parameters are {}",queryParams);
    return mongoTemplate.find(query,clazz);
}
```

}
`

Comment: What else spring data repositories aparot from mongo are you using? JPA, Redis?

Comment: I am using Oracle Datasource and ElasticSearch repositories in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

> You should use MongoRepository interface.

[MongoRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html)